# hiding query string parameters htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, querystringparameter

Hi I want To Ask How Can I convert http://abc.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id=16 to http://abc.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id/16 using .htaccess mod_write
means the user see this link
abc.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id/16
when he clicks a hyperlink having source
abc.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id=16

Comment: You cannot do what You ask. But You could transform the URLs into `http://abc.tk/comments.php/post_referrel_id/16`...

Comment: can you tell me how Brother........

Answer (score 0):

you need research, sir.
check this easy [tuto](http://blog.eprakash.info/2012/01/10-useful-ways-to-rewrite-url-using.html)

And for your tips, don't use `?` in the rewritten url.

here is a quick code to do that (with `?` in the rewritten url)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^comment.php?post_referrel_id/([0-9]+)$ comment.php?post_referrel_id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^comments.php?post_referrel_id/(.*)$ comments.php/post_referrel_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You may have to add a redirect from one form to another. The above code just tells the server that the /16 is the same with =16

Answer (score 0):

use these lines of code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.tk
RewriteRule ^comments.php?post_referrel_id=([0-9]+)$ comments.php?post_referrel_id/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this will be redirect `comments.php?post_referrel_id=16` to `comments.php?post_referrel_id/16`

Comment: my Brother This is not working ..... dont know why.....can you explain the above code

Comment: for using rewrite mode your apache mod_rewrite module should be enabled.
these code tells apache to redirect each url that contains abc.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id=[numeric] to abc.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id/[numeric]

Comment: hey brother i am using 000webhost server....and mod_write is enabled on  it......but don know why this code is not working........

Comment: i don't know why this is not working for you.
look at this : http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: i had seen this page before ....... used the commands according to it but it didn't work out